# Transforming a data frame column into a counter matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame like this. Invoices are transformed into a table where each row has a single product. This table consists of millions of rows -

| invoice | products |
| --- | --- |
| INVC1 | xx |
| INVC1 | yy |
| INVC1 | zz |
| INVC1 | aa |
| INVC2 | xx |
| INVC2 | aa |
| INVC2 | bb |
| INVC2 | cc |

Now I want to create a table like the one below where I can see how many times each product is purchased with other products-

|  | xx | yy | zz | aa | bb | cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| yy | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| zz | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| aa | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| bb | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| cc | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Is there any numpy/pandas way to create a table like this? Or, is there any optimized way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us use `pd.crosstab` then `dot`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['invoice'],df['products'])
out = s.T.dot(s)
Out[196]: 
products  aa  bb  cc  xx  yy  zz
products                        
aa         2   1   1   2   1   1
bb         1   1   1   1   0   0
cc         1   1   1   1   0   0
xx         2   1   1   2   1   1
yy         1   0   0   1   1   1
zz         1   0   0   1   1   1
```